# ScrollView always go back to the starting position after closing subview

Tags: ios, swift

My application has the main view and multiple subviews. What I want to do is when `View2?.removeFromSuperview()` then scrollView would start from the beginning. Because now I put subviews *ON* the main view and then when I go back to main view, scrollview is at the same position as it was before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
offset = CGPoint(x: -yourScrollView.adjustedContentInset.left,y: -yourScrollView.adjustedContentInset.top)    
yourScrollView.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

try this

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much.

Comment: you welcome. But I think this kind of questions already exist; so from next time you should try to find already existing ones. So you won't get down vote ;)